# How can I throw exception on PHP, DateTime::createFromFormat()?

Tags: php, exception

I'm a newbie on throwing Exceptions and I'm not getting how to throw an Exception when using this PHP base method, DateTime::createFromFormat()

The case is the following:

```
private function obtainMostRecentFile($fileNamesArray, $start, $lenght) {
    foreach ($fileNamesArray as $row) {
        $i++;
        $format = 'Ymd';
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, substr($row, $start, $lenght));
        $date_in_format[$i] = $date->format('Ymd');
    }
    return (max($date_in_format));
}
```

I have this method, and I need to find a way of throwing an Exception when the `DateTime::createFromFormat($format, substr($row, $start, $lenght));` does not run correctly.

For example:

If I call `$this->obtainMostRecentFile("GeoLiteCity_20101201.zip", 12, 8);` the function return the output that they should return.

If I call `$this->obtainMostRecentFile("GeoLiteCity_201.zip", 12, 8);` the function return the output `Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\testes\testecsv4.php on line 440`.

Normaly I do something like this:

```
if (is_null($someVariable)) {
    throw new Exception("null variable");
}
```

Can you give me some clues on how to thrown Exception for the `DateTime::createFromFormat()` ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) is called with an invalid value, it returs `false`. `false` does not have a method `format`, so this is where your app breaks down:

```
$date_in_format[$i] = $date->format('Ymd');
```

You should include a check before that:

```
$format = 'Ymd';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, substr($row, $start, $lenght));
if($date === false) {
    // throw an exception here!
}
$date_in_format[$i] = $date->format('Ymd');
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case when `DateTime::createFromFormat` is not run correctly it returns something that is not an object (probably boolean `false`). Check that variable and throw Exception if it's not an object

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, substr($row, $start, $lenght)); 
if (!is_object($date)) { // or $date === false
    throw new Exception('DateTime::createFromFormat error');
}
```

Comment: This reply is a valid one too. I have tested also. Thanks a lot!